# Detect iPad device with an option to view the regular site JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript that detects an iPad and redirect them to the mobile site. I also have a link that allow users to leave the mobile site to view the full site. However, when they click on the link to view the full site, the JavaScript fires again and redirects them back to the mobile site. How do I fix this? Down below is a sample of my JavaScript code.

```
if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') != -1)) {
    document.location = "http://www.sample.com/mobilego.aspx";
}
```

Comment: Set a cookie that says they want the full version, and then check the cookie before redirecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` to store a flag that overrides the redirect.

E.g. on mobile site

```
if (window.sessionStorage) sessionStorage.setItem("beenOnMobileSite",true)
```

and on main site

```
if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') != -1
  && !sessionStorage.getItem("beenOnMobileSite")) {
    document.location = "http://www.sample.com/mobilego.aspx";
}
```

use `localStorage` instead of `sessionStorage` to make the override persistent.

If the mobile site and main site are on different servers, they won't have access to the same storage. One solution to this is to add a parameter to the link to the main page, and check for the parameter in your script on the main page. If the parameter is present, override the redirect as before, but also set the `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` item as above to make it stick.

Comment: Thanks! That works. However, if I'm using localStorage and the user migrates over to the desktop site and exit out the browser, how can I redirect them back to the mobile site when they open up their browser again? I assume that would work if you're using sessionStorage, but I've tried that one and it doesn't even let me migrate over to the desktop site.

Comment: `sessionStorage` should do what you're looking for (see https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/iphone/conceptual/safarijsdatabaseguide/name-valuestorage/name-valuestorage.html) - what exactly happens when you try it?

Comment: When I tried it, it directs me to my mobile site when I first visit the address. However, when I click on the link which leaves the mobilesite and go to the full time, it redirects me back to my mobilesite.

Comment: Nevermind. It works. It's just the update of the iOS is outofdate and there's a bug that affects Safari browser, but it works on Google Chrome. Thanks!